Azure App Service - Why App Service environment variables doesn't work for virtual directory?
I have two web apps deployed in a single Azure App Service instance:

The first one has a home directory in "site\wwwroot".
The second (api) has a home directory in "site\wwwroot\wwwroot".

I created a new virtual application in the app service - path mappings. I set a name and I set a physical path to:
site\wwwroot\wwwroot
I also set multiple environment variables (App settings) in the app service to override the default ones in the appsettings.json files of the both web apps:

site\wwwroot\appsettings.json
site\wwwroot\wwwroot\appsettings.json

Now the env. variables from the app service are overriding the variables in the first web app (site\wwwroot\appsettings.json). However the override of the variables of the second app (site\wwwroot\wwwroot\appsettings.json) is not working.
Does Azure App Service environment variables also override app. settings from the virtual application or what am I missing here?

Your virtual directory has to be under site/wwwroot folder itself.How you arae deploying your app ?

I'm not sure how the web app/s is/are deployed. I have source code but the deployment is done from someone else. In the VS solution, there are two web projects. They are deployed to a single azure app service within the folder structure I wrote in the main description.

Ok..Can you please share the screen shot of your both project structures.

Sure, here: https://imgur.com/a/rJOM1G5

Are you still facing issue ?


Does Azure App Service environment variables also override app. settings from the virtual application

Yes, you can override app settings of the virtual application using Environment Variables.
Refer my SOThread to deploy Virtual Applications to single Azure App Service.

I am able to override the settings for both Main and Virtual application.

My application folder structure:


Your Virtual application has to be deployed to the site/wwwroot main directory.



If you have same key in both the Apps, and if you set the key in App Service Environment Variables, both the applications value will be updated.



I have set the same key with name CommonKey in both the apps, you can see that it is overriding the value in 2 applications.

Output:


To avoid confusion, make sure the key names are different for both the apps.


Thanks for confirmation! In my case the issue seems to be in the way how appsettings.json file has been created and stored because it's not directly in the root of the second web app. The appsettings.json file is in a sub-folder of the second web app. Seems to be a valid reason why it's not working in my case.
